# How to make docker generate only differential layer for a pre-existing file change in base image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to generate a docker image using Dockerfiles the sequence is as follows

1)Create an image using dokerfile that will copy abc.txt (size 200kb) in image

2)Create another image using another docker file that will use previously generated image(in step (1)) as base image and copy file abc.txt(appended data and size=400kb)

**When I check the layers of second image it shows the base image layers with second layer having size 200kb due to 200kb file(abc.txt) and top layer with 400 kb due to 400kb file(abc.txt)**

**What i am expecting is on the top layer only the 200kb change of the file abc.txt should appear in second image but thats not the case when i do this.**

Is there any other way I can achieve this?
Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thsese are my dockerfile contents
:-

### (1)for 1st image and when abc.txt size is 200kb:

From ubuntu

COPY abc.txt /home/root/abc.txt

---

After this I build the image using

docker build -t ubuntu2 .

### (2)For 2nd image and when I appended abc.txt resulting in 400kb size:

From ubuntu2

COPY abc.txt /home/root/abc.txt

---

I modified abc.txt and overwrite existing Dockerfile with above contents
and built the image using

docker build -t ubuntu3 .

Comment: Show the Dockerfiles please. Someone will downvote you if you dont ;) Also note that the next layer allways contains all the previous layers and not only the difference between them.

Comment: I have added the dockerfile contents as you said.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you replace the file `abc.txt` with another one with the same name, so the changes you make are deleting and adding a file. In my opinion to just have the difference, you have to use a `RUN` command instead of `COPY` like this :

```
RUN echo "data to add" >> /home/root/abc.txt
```

Comment: But in case of different file like a war,jar whats the way to achieve this?

Comment: I dont want to use run echo  as the contents to append the file can be large. I want to copy file the existing file so that the new layer contains only the changes. Is there any other way?